# How do you find the difference of a field key for two data points belonging to different timestamps?

Tags: influxdb

I have the following data:

```
INSERT table1,adwords_id=123-456-7890 total_spending=0 1538377201000000000
INSERT table1,adwords_id=123-456-7890 total_spending=110 1538463601000000000
INSERT table1,adwords_id=123-456-7890 total_spending=120 1538550001000000000
```

And I want to write a query to find the difference of total_spending between two timestamps.

For example, let say I want to find the difference of total_spending between `1538377201000000000 + 1h` and `1538550001000000000 + 1h`

Doing it line by line will be:

```
v1 = SELECT last(total_spending) FROM table1 WHERE "adwords_id" = '123-456-7890' AND time < 1538377201000000000 + 1h

v2 = SELECT last(total_spending) FROM table1 WHERE "adwords_id" = '123-456-7890' AND time < 1538550001000000000 + 1h
```

And the answer will be `v2-v1`

How can I do this in one query? (*so I can run this across many adwords_id*)

Answer (score 0):

The below should work for you.

You need to have variable values for @t1, @t2 and @adwordsId.

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT TOP 1 total_spending
    FROM Table1
    WHERE adwords_id = @adwordsId
    AND time < @t2
    ORDER BY time DESC
) - 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 total_spending
    FROM Table1
    WHERE adwords_id = @adwordsId
    AND time < @t1
    ORDER BY time DESC
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming total_spending is cumulative for each adwords_id, I would try this:

```
SELECT last("total_spending") - first("total_spending") FROM Table1 WHERE time >= t1 AND time <= t2 GROUP BY "adwords_id"
```